# One Author Disappeared

Tags: article

I want to list the original author first and then the reviser. However, I totally lost the first author by using the following code. Is there a good way to fix this, please? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{S. S}
\author{Revised by T. H and X. S}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How clever do you want to be? The unclever way is: `\author{S. S\\[6pt] Revised by T. H. and X. S}`.  But there are better ways....

Comment: I actually tried this just now. But the second line became italic, which is not what I want. OK, I figured it out by using \textup. But what are the better ways you mentioned.

Comment: Do you load any packages that affect the output of the `\author` macro? The second author line does not become italicized in the example code you gave if @jon's suggestion is implemented.

Comment: That might be the case. I used a dozen of packages in fact.

Comment: `\author` defines the author list: it's not additive. That's the defined behaviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to add to the existing `\@maketitle` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\def\redactor#1{\def\@redactor{#1}}
\def\@maketitle{% <-- NB this is the definition from article.cls; it may well not work (well) with other classes!
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author\\ % <-- the \\ is added
        \@redactor%  <-- added; you could put the string 'Revised by' here, but it is less flexible
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

% Note: I'm inclined to include 'metadata' in the preamble, but it is not required in this case....
\title{Title}
\author{S. S}
\redactor{Revised by T. H and X. S}
\date{August 2015}
\begin{document}
% \title{Title}
% \author{S. S}
% \redactor{Revised by T. H and X. S}
% \date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```